# How to transform List<A> to TreeSet<B>

Tags: java

How can I transform `List<A> aList` to `TreeSet<B>`, where for `A a` we have the following mapping `B b = a.getElement()`?

Answer (score 4):

It can be done like this in Java 8 assuming that `list` is your List of `A`

```
list.stream().map(A::getElement).collect(toCollection(TreeSet::new))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java8, you can use stream api

```
TreeSet<B> listB = listA.stream()
                .map(a -> a.getElement())
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new));
```

If you have to deal with pre-lambda environment my suggestion will be to create interface

```
interface Converter<S, T> {
        T convert(S source);
    }
```

nice utility class

```
class ConvertColection {
        public static <S, T> TreeSet<T> toTreeset(Collection<S> source,
                Converter<S, T> converter) {
            TreeSet<T> result = new TreeSet<T>();
            for (S s : source) {
                result.add(converter.convert(s));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

you could extend it to add more methods, or made them more generic, ie by passing collection class and instantiate it in method.

then you will execute this by calling

```
TreeSet<B> listB = ConvertColection.toTreeset(listA, 
            new Converter<A, B>() {
                    @Override
                    public B convert(A a) {
                        return a.getElement();
                    }
        });
```

you could also create converters as singletons and reuse them.
obviously thera are bunch of libraries which will do this for you

Comment: Shouldnt it be `Collectors.toCollection(TreeSet::new)` for the JAVA 8 solution?